# Getting the actual height of content size fitter parent

Tags: unity, gui

I have a parent gameobject (`Empty`) with a content size fitter with horizontal and vertical fit set to preferred size which is also a `Horizontal Layout Group` with `Control Child size` width and height enabled:

[image]

It has got a `TextMeshPro` text as child, and now, as the text expands the parent also expands. The problem is, I want to get the height of this parent. And if I use this:

```
var rect = parent.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>.rect
Debug.Log($"Width: {rect.width}, height: {rect.height}");
```

or even,

```
var mValue = parent.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>.sizeDelta;
Debug.Log($"sizeDeltax: {mValue.x}, sizeDeltaY: {mValue.y}");
```

they both give 0.

I require some way to extract the expanded width and height. How can I do that?

NOTE: The content of the child i.e. text is being assigned dynamically, also the parent/text is a prefab being instantiated dynamically i.e. via `Instantiate`, and this is not done in the start method.

Okay, here's more detail about the hierarchy and stuff:
**The hierarchy**

[image]

**Parent**:
[image]

**Interface**
[image]

**MessageField**
[image]

**OutputSection**
[image]

**Viewport**
[image]

**ChatPanel**
[image]

So, eventually chat bubbles are supposed to stack on top of one another, they get parented to ChatPanel, and each child is a prefab instantiated as mentioned above, the prefab detail are:

**hierarchy**
[image]

**stackItem**
[image]

**ItemParent**
[image]

**Tag**
[image]

**TextItem**  (Note the MessageTextItem is basically not used, it's there for some old code reasons)
[image]

**ChatTextBubble**
[image]

[image]
These are expanded below:
[image]
[image]

When I send message, I log the width and height of the white part of the chat bubble which is basically the **chatTextBubble above, using the code: **

```
   var expRect = chatTextBubble.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            Debug.Log($"dvz:: expRect width is: {expRect.rect.width} and height is: {expRect.rect.height}");
```

and it logs 0. Please tell me what am I doing wrong. It looks similar to below example but, not working.

This is what it looks like during gameplay: [image]

EDIT:
I just noticed, the **chatTextBubble** has this during gameplay:

[image]
but, logs 0 when I log with the above mentioned code.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your project hierarchy while the game is running and the child UI objects are spawned?

Answer (score 2):

Something is amiss with your setup, because RectTransform.rect *will* contain correct updated values as `ContentSizeFitter` manipulates its dimensions.

Here is a minimum verifiable example. Project hierarchy:
[image: project heirarchy]

Code, attached to Test Controller GameObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetParentSize : MonoBehaviour
{

    public RectTransform parent;
    public GameObject childPrefab;
    public Text readout;
    float timer = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= .5f)
        {
            var child = Instantiate(childPrefab);
            child.transform.SetParent(parent.transform);

            timer = 0;
        }
        readout.text = string.Format("Parent Width: {0} units",parent.rect.width.ToString());
    }
}
```

Code instantiates a UI prefab every .5s and sets the parent of the instanced gameobject to the gameobject with the `ContentSizeFitter` and `HorizontalLayout` components. Every frame it updates the UI readout text with the width of the gameobject with the `ContentSizeFitter`.

This is how the parent gameobject is configured in the inspector:
[image: Parent in inspector]

This is how the Test Controller is wired up:[image]

And here it is in action:
[image: Demo]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, sorry I replied so late, let me check this out.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, share more details of your set up -- what you are trying to do *should* work...

Comment: I'll post the entire thing

Comment: I posted the entire hiearchy and all related content, could you please take a look?

Comment: I wonder if the value I get is 0 because the child is a text component

Comment: let me know if I can add any more information

Comment: also please see my latest code

Comment: it seems the size is evaluated during update? : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1247236/how-to-get-size-of-dynamically-created-layout-elem.html , this is so inefficient, how else can we obtain it?

Comment: @BumbleBee Thanks for adding all the extra information -- I'll have a closer look later today...

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and I found the solution was to use [ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate](https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.LayoutRebuilder.html#UnityEngine_UI_LayoutRebuilder_ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate_UnityEngine_RectTransform_) ([2018 version](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html)):

```cs
LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(go.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
```

I can then get the dimensions with: `go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.x` (Width) or `.y` (Height)